# Is it safe to split large encrypted GnuPG file then cat and decrypt later?

Tags: security, gnupg, cat

I have a GnuPG encrypted `tar.gz` file that is about 20 GB in size and I need to split it then backup to another machine.

Is it safe to `split` large encrypted GnuPG file without compromising security and file integrity or damage it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Concatenating previously split file recreates every bit of it, regardless of file type or content. You may want to take care of metadata though (permissions etc.). And mind your chunks order, of course.

Splitting cannot compromise security. I mean: if it could, the attackers would split the large file themselves to make their task easier. This would be a serious flaw in encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as the final output file is identical to the original input file there's no problem.

In any case, you can't introduce a security problem this way, the worst you can do is to introduce corruption and lose the original file altogether.

I'd do a checksum of the original file before splitting so that you can verify it's integrity on the far end after concatenation. (md5sum, sha1sum, and sha256sum sum are all checksum utilities commonly found on modern systems).